# How to set the default jvm args to gradle application plugin?

Tags: gradle

I use the gradle application plugin to generate the application folder.
The `installApp` task provides a start script for me, but I have no idea how to set the jvm args from `build.gradle`.

Some jvm args I needed, such as `file.encoding`. I just modify the start script to set the `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS` variable

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##############################################################################
##
##  MuzeeS3Deployer start up script for UN*X
##
##############################################################################

# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and MUZEE_S_DEPLOYER_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=" -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 "
```

If the args not set, my console cannot show messages well:

```
qty:MuzeeS3Deployer qrtt1$ ./build/install/MuzeeS3Deployer/bin/MuzeeS3Deployer d
2012/10/14 #U###12:02:03 SyncCommand main
ĵ#i: no aws credentials found at /Users/qrtt1/AwsCredentials.properties
```

When I set the encoding:

```
qty:MuzeeS3Deployer qrtt1$ ./build/install/MuzeeS3Deployer/bin/MuzeeS3Deployer d
2012/10/14 下午 12:04:19 SyncCommand main
警告: no aws credentials found at /Users/qrtt1/AwsCredentials.properties
```

---

I got the solution from [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84889/peter-niederwieser). Finally, I make a minor changes to the scripts:

```
startScripts {
    doLast {
        unixScript.text = unixScript.text.replace('DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=""', 'DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"')
        windowsScript.text = windowsScript.text.replace('DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=', 'DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is currently no special support for setting `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS`. However, you can do something like:

```
startScripts {
    doLast {
        unixScript.text = unixScript.text.replace('DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=""', 'DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"')
    }
}
```

You may want to do something similar for `windowsScript`.

Comment: Do not use this anymore! This sollution is outdated.

Comment: yes, now you can add in build.gradle something like:
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['-Dxxxxx']

Comment: the issue would be if you need to enter different settings for Windows and Linux (f.e. paths). in that case, the solution from  Peter seems to be easiest one.

Answer (score 27):

Support for JVM arguments was added in Gradle 1.7: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#configureApplicationDefaultJvmArgs

For example, for setting `file.encoding`, you can do:

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['-Dfile.encoding=utf-8']
```